What version of Qiskit is best for solving combinatorial optimization problems using QAOA and parameter tuning?
I am working on solving combinatorial optimization problems using QAOA (Quantum Approximate Optimization Algorithm) in Qiskit. My goal is to tune the parameters of QAOA (such as gamma and beta) and use quantum circuits to optimize the solution.
However, I am encountering some issues with the latest versions of Qiskit, especially related to differences in the way import packages are handled across versions. The changes in API and module structure have led to confusion, and I am struggling to adapt my code to these changes.
Could you recommend a version of Qiskit that is stable, widely used, and well-suited for solving combinatorial optimization problems with QAOA? I need a version where the QAOA implementation and its parameter optimizers are reliable and easy to use.
Thank you for your help!

Recommendation questions are off-topic. Aside from that, you're asking opinion-based questions ("stable', "well-used", "well-suited", "reliable", "easy to use" - all this is up for interpretation).
